# Android Augmented Reality App : Rotate spherical coordinate to device coordinate system

Tags: java, android, matrix, rotation

I'm creating a android AR app.

My goal is to print on the device screen a element located using **spherical coordinate** (bearing, elevation, distance is not relevant in my case) in the user coordinate system (North, Down, East). 
e.g. : North pole this (0°, 0°). (90°, 10°) would be at my East, 10° above the ground.

Using with Android getRotationMatrix and co, I was able to print a element located using **cartesian coordinate** (x, y, z) in the user coordinate system. This is roughly the **matrix product** of the element vector and the rotation matrix, rotating from user coord system to device coord system.

But what about **spherical coordinate** ? Do I have to hand write this rotation matrix ? I cannot find resources about spherical coordinate and rotation matrix... I must be missing something...

I thought about transforming spherical coordinate to cartesian, but it just seems like a workaround.

I don't use any extra framework (but I can if needed).

Answer (score 0):

After digging in Stack Exchange Mathematics, it seems that converting to cartesian coordinate is the way to go. 
See :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59255/can-you-not-rotate-spherical-coordinates
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92301/transforming-from-one-spherical-coordinate-system-to-another
[Rotating body from spherical coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278417/rotating-body-from-spherical-coordinates)